# Python 3.4 support of print operations with redirectors >>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm going through some examples from a text book. The source code below fails with the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_db_file.py", line 39, in <module>
    storeDbase(db)
  File "make_db_file.py", line 12, in storeDbase
    print >> dbfile, key
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

```
def storeDbase(db, dbfilename=dbfilename):
    "formatted dump of database to flat file"
    import sys
    dbfile = open(dbfilename, 'w')
    for key in db:
        print >> dbfile, key
        for (name, value) in db[key].items():
            print >> dbfile, name + RECSEP + repr(value)
    print >> dbfile, ENDDB
    dbfile.close()
```

When I run this code under Python 2.7 it works as expected. Can someone please point me in the right direction. What has changed in the `print` function that prevents this from working in Python 3.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function and not a keyword. So, if you want to redirect the output, you have to set the optional parameter `file` (default value is [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)), like this:

```
print(key, file=dbfile)
```

Take a look at the [**Print is a function**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) paragraph, from the official documentation about what changed in Python 3.

Comment: that helped immensely. Is this in the Documentation?

Comment: @d_blk Yes, I added a link to the documentation which relates changes of `print()` from Python 2 to 3. :)